# Passing AWS Credentials in Jenkins into Ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to pass an aws creds I have stored within jenkins into an ansible playbook and it doesnt seems to be taking it. I've done research and seems like everybody is storing their creds in the jenkins file. Is it possible to pass the variable into an ansible-playbook? Below is my current situation

[Jenkins Creds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxOuS.png)

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('GIT Code Checkout'){
           steps{
               git branch: 'ansible', credentialsId: 'test-pipeline', url: 'https://github.com/newbtech'
           }
    environment{
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials('aws-key')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('aws_secret_access_key')
        }
        stage('Run Tools Playbook'){
           steps{
               ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'root-key', 
               disableHostKeyChecking: true, installation: 'ansible', 
               extras: "-e HOST=${SERVER}", 
               inventory: 'ansible/host.inv', 
               playbook: 'ansible/cstest.yml'                
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Ansible-Playbook

```
---
- hosts: "{{ HOST }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "S3 Pull - Ubunutu"
      aws_s3:
        aws_access_key: "aws-key"
        aws_secret_key: "aws_secret_access_key"
        bucket: "images"
        object: "ubuntu.deb"
        dest: "/tmp/ubuntu.deb"
        mode: get
      when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
      vars:
         ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Hi Newbietech welcome to SO. Based on the code snippet, why are you even specifying `aws_access_key:` and `...secret_key:` on your task, since they will be pulled from the environment variable automatically and also won't be the completely wrong string literals that you have now?

Comment: Are you talking about the jenkins file or the playbook?

Comment: I guess he means in the playbook. Normally Ansible AWS modules read the environment variables from ansible host, but that's not your case. I am not familiar with Jenkins, but I guess defining environment variables in Jenkins doesn't mean exporting them to the host machine.

Comment: Even if it works, it doesn't make sense to pull them from environment variables. I may have multiple credentials stored in Jenkins and like to use them for different cases or playbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the plugin [Credentials Binding](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/)

I've tried to use snippet generator for the *Pipeline Syntax* for this plugin, but it wasn't helpful at all for me.
Define a `withCredentials` block in the pipeline under the step you want the credentials to be available:

```yaml
withCredentials(
[[
    $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
    accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    credentialsId: 'aws',  # ID of AWS credentials in Jenkins
    secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
]])
```

In your pipeline:

```yaml
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage ('Git checkout')
    {
      steps
      {
        git branch: 'ansible', credentialsId: 'test-pipeline', url: 'https://github.com/newbtech'
      } 
    }
    stage('Run Tools Playbook')
    {
      steps
      {
        withCredentials(
            [[
                $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                credentialsId: 'aws-key',
                secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
            ]])
        {
          ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'root-key', 
          disableHostKeyChecking: true, installation: 'ansible', 
          extras: "-e HOST=${SERVER}", 
          inventory: 'ansible/host.inv', 
          playbook: 'ansible/cstest.yml' 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can define credentials in your playbook as follows:

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ HOST }}"
  tasks:
  - name: "S3 Pull - Ubunutu"
    aws_s3:
      aws_access_key: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
      aws_secret_key: "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
      bucket: "images"
      object: "ubuntu.deb"
      dest: "/tmp/ubuntu.deb"
      mode: get
    when: ansible_facts['os_family'] == "Debian"
    vars:
       ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```